# Рекурсия по дереву

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, дерево

Есть примерно такой набор данных и по ним нужно построить дерево категорий.

```
Main
   DATA
      Images
           1.png
      Videos
           1.avi
      Music
   TEST


0:{name: "Images",  .., parent: "Data"}
1:{name: "1.png", .., parent: "Images"}
2:{name: "Musics", .., parent: "Data"}
3:{name: "Data", .., parent: "MAIN"}
4:{name: "Videos", ..", parent: "Data"}
5:{name: "1.avi", ..", parent: "Videos"}
6:{name: "Test", ..", parent: "MAIN"}
```

Есть функция для построения этого дерева

```
function tree(parent, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        if (parent !== item.parent) {
            return;
        }
    //build tree   
    tree(item.name, arr);
    });
}
```

Всё работает и строится, но при относительно небольшом наборе данных (например при 50 элементов - 2550 проходов) количество проходов огромное, каким образом можно улучшить проход чтобы уменьшить количество итераций? Или есть какой-то другой подход в этом случаи?

Comment: непонятно что у вас за массив, если в каждом индексе массива все разложено по ключам . что тогда за сложности. ?!

Comment: @L11VADIS вроде бы всё понятно написано, при относительно небольшом количестве данных, больше количество итераций. Ресурсы не бесконечные.

Comment: так а что, нельзя просто взять итый массив и спросить в какой парент тебя положить ?

Comment: @L11VADIS берем i-ый элемент массива и проходим каждый элемент массива спрашивая нужно ли его вложить туда и так с каждым элементом массива. В итоге получается точно такое же количество итераций.

Comment: 'Main.DATA[arr[0].parent]'  а так почему нельзя

Comment: @L11VADIS не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, можете пожалуйста пояснить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70845/discussion-between-l11vadis-and-kostya).